# WPF WebBrowser Control Does not load with Impersonation

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, impersonation

I have a WPF application which impersonation. The users login with their credentials, impersonation is done using Logon methods and all works fine except for WebBrowser Control.
There are two issues

1. When impersonated the WebBrowser Control does not show up on screen. I can see the requests being sent in Fiddler, but it just dont show up on screen.
2. The credentials of the impersonated user is not sent. We use the windows authentication. the User recieved on web application is the one which is originally running the thread. If we open IE as process and then try to open the same application it works fine, but dont for WebBrowser Control.

I have tried all sorts of options but could not find an solution. Can someone help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Also, as a requirement i cannot use any other web control. Have to go by WPF WebBrowser Control

Comment: What options have you tried?

Comment: Nothing worked out. Seems the internal COM Component does not work with impersonation. We changed the approach and used pdf viewer, we render the PDF from server and show it to user in PDF control.